# Attaching event handler on click pointing to function in class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to attach an event handler on click pointing to function in class? Like this:

```
class SomeClass {
  render() {
    this.parentElement.append(`
      <form>
        <input type="text" onkeydown="${this.keydown()}"/>
        <button onclick="this.onclick();">Submit</button>
        <span></span>
      </form>
    `);
  }

  onkeydown() {}
  onclick() {}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do it like that! But you can change the `render` to create your elements using `document.createElement` and then you can set the `.onclick =` property of the elements within that scope! Or attach the event listener after you append the HTML (select those elements and then use `.onclick =`

Answer (score 0):

The way you've done it here? No.  Especially since `append` will only append nodes, not create nodes. Text *is* a node, but you won't see your form, just the HTML that would produce a form.  However, even if you use `innerHTML` instead, it still won't work.

For the first function, you're not putting a reference to `onkeypress`, you're literally calling the function when you call `render`.  If you remove the parenthesis you just wind calling the default value of the function.  The same as if you put `onkeypress.toString()`.  Not very helpful.

The second function, `onclick` is a bit trickier. It *does* call a function, just not the one you were hoping for.  [Understanding the `this` keyword in JavaScript is tricky.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)  In this case, even though you're writing the html in a class, when the button is clicked the context of `this` is not that class.  Instead it's the element that has the onclick listener attached, `button`.  So what function does it call?  Itself.  Over and over again.  This is a very good example of why it's not a good idea to name functions the same as native ones.  Sadly though, even if you change it's name to something safer, like `handleClick`, it still doesn't work.  The `button` (the current value of `this`) just doesn't have the function you're trying to reference.

So, is it possible?  Depends on what you're looking for.  If you render the node and then add an event listener in the more traditional ways, sure.  Just add `this.parentElement.querySelector('button').onclick = this.handleClick;` or `this.parentElement.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown)` after you add the form to the dom (using `innerHTML` or [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), instead of `append`). Or follow [Ibrahim's sugestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434713/attaching-event-handler-on-click-pointing-to-function-in-class/43435155#comment-73927328) and create the elements using `createElement` and attaching the event handlers before you append them to the parent element. Though, if you want to have access to your classes `this`, you might want to [bind them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) first.